- nested templates - Referencing Another YAML File Inside the YAML File of databricks asset bundles
In my try to modulize the databricks asset bundle yaml config file. I'm trying to find out if it's possible to reference or include another YAML file within a job configuration YAML file.
For example:
**Tasks_reference.yaml**

tasks:
  - task_key: task_0
    notebook_task:
      notebook_path: /path/to/task_1
      source: WORKSPACE
    existing_cluster_id: 0714-12131312-qdx4z4gi


**Etl_job.yaml**
include:
  - Tasks_reference.yaml

resources:
  jobs:
    source_a_simple_etl:
      tasks:
        - task_key: task_0
          existing_cluster_id: 0714-154908-dsadsa
        # Additional tasks...

I tried with the "include" keyword but doesn’t seem to work.
Does anyone know if this kind of referencing is possible in the YAML dab configurations? If so, how can I correctly include one YAML file within another?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Did you get any error after your try? if yes, please provide that for better understanding.
